# ExtendedFloatingActionButton end alignment in BottomAppBar with margin

Tags: android, material-design, androidx

I'm trying to add ExtendedFloatingActionButton along with BottomAppBar with **fabAlignmentMode** set to **end**. The extended FAB is moved to end on setting the property but I'm unable to add margins to it. Attached is a image showing the same.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomappbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
        app:hideOnScroll="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_website_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Site"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomappbar_main"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta02'
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am removed the `anchor` properties and margins works nice.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not a great combination of `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` with `BottomAppBar` as it's intended to use with `FloatingActionButton`. I have played with these duo and found that margin not working unless I add a big one.

For your scenario, I have added `layout_marginEnd` with `145dp` and then it starts to work. If you need more then try with some other values.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_website_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Site"
    android:layout_marginEnd="145dp"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomappbar_main"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: May not be a good idea to use it with BottomAppBar but the docs example suggested that and I went ahead with it. Yes, applying more margin allows to move the button. It looks off though while shrinking and expanding so I went the FloatingActionButton way instead of ExtendedFloatingActionButton.